# Timeout the thread if any bundle is taking lot of time

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, executorservice, future

I am working on a project in which I will have different Bundles. Let's take an example, Suppose I have 5 bundles and each of those bundles will have a method name `process`.

Now currently, I am calling the `process method` of all those 5 bundles sequentially, one by one and then I am writing to the database. But that's what I don't want.

1. I need to call all those 5 Bundles `process method` in parallel using multithread and then write to the database.
2. And I also want to have some timeout feature for those threads. I will be having a default timeout settings for all the threads for the bundles. If any bundle is taking some higher time than the timeout settings I have, then I want to timeout those threads and then log back saying this bundle got timeout bcoz it was taking lot of time.

I hope question is clear enough...

Below is the code I have so far which is calling process method sequentially one by one.

```
public void processEvents(final Map<String, Object> eventData) {

    final Map<String, String> outputs = (Map<String, String>)eventData.get(BConstants.EVENT_HOLDER);

    for (final BundleRegistration.BundlesHolderEntry entry : BundleRegistration.getInstance()) {

        final Map<String, String> response = entry.getPlugin().process(outputs);

        // write to the database.
        System.out.println(response);
    }
}
```

I am not sure what is the best and efficient way to do this? Because, in future, it might be possible that I will have more than 5 bundles.

Can anyone provide me an example of how can I achieve this? Any help will be appreciated on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not too difficult to achieve what you want, but you should be aware that both with concurrency and timeouts you get added complexity, especially when it comes to error handling.

For instance, threads that are running when a timeout occurs may keep running after the timeout. Only well behaved threads that cooperate by handling an interrupt signal will be able to stop succefully in the middle of processing.

You must also make sure that individual bundle entries may be processed in parallel, i.e. that the are thread safe. If they modify some shared resource while processing, then you might get strange errors as a result.

I was also wondering whether you wanted to include the database writing to each of these threads. If so, you will need to handle interruptions while writing to the database; e.g. by rolling back a transaction.

Anyways, to get thread pooling and a total timeout for all threads, you can use `ExecutorService` with (for instance) a fixed pool size and invoke all threads using the `invokeAll` method.

The following attempt is most probably flawed and error handling is by no means complete, but it should give you a starting point.

First, an implementation of Callable for your threads:

```
public class ProcessBundleHolderEntry implements Callable {
    private BundleRegistration.BundlesHolderEntry entry;
    private Map<String, String> outputs;

    public ProcessBundleHolderEntry(BundleRegistration.BundlesHolderEntry entry, Map<String, String> outputs) {
        this.entry = entry;
        this.outputs = outputs;
    }

    public Object call() throws Exception {
        final Map<String, String> response = entry.getPlugin().process(outputs);
        // write to the database.
        System.out.println(response);
        return response;
    }
}
```

and now, the modified `processEvents` method:

```
public void processEvents(final Map<String, Object> eventData) {
    ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    List<ProcessBundleHolderEntry> entries = new ArrayList<ProcessBundleHolderEntry>();

    Map<String, String> outputs = (Map<String, String>)eventData.get(BConstants.EVENT_HOLDER);
    for (BundleRegistration.BundlesHolderEntry entry : BundleRegistration.getInstance()) {
        ProcessBundleHolderEntry processBundleHolderEntry = new ProcessBundleHolderEntry(entry, outputs);
        entries.add(processBundleHolderEntry);
    }

    try {
        List<Future<Object>> futures = pool.invokeAll(entries, 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        for (int i = 0; i < futures.size(); i++) {
            // This works since the list of future objects are in the
            // same sequential order as the list of entries
            Future<Object> future = futures.get(i);
            ProcessBundleHolderEntry entry = entries.get(i);
            if (!future.isDone()) {
                // log error for this entry
            }
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // handle this exception!
    }
}
```

Comment: One quick question on this. `processEvents` method will be getting everytime for any new events. So inside that method, I will be creating the threads everytime using ExecutorService just like the way you have done?

Comment: And in this case, the timeout is specific to each thread, meaning if I have 2 bundles, then that thread that is executing bundle-A, will get timeout if it is not able to process withing that time frame right?

Comment: Yes, everytime processEvents is called it will spawn new threads (max 5 in current impl) and wait for them to finish or timeout. If `processEvents` is called from another thread before the previous one was finished, then they will also work simultaneously.

Comment: I see.. Should I be declaring ExecutorService as private final at the top rather than creating one every time the processEvents method is called.? Any thoughts?

Comment: Yeah, that's probably better. It depends a bit on what behaviour you want. Can you get two simultaneous calls to processEvents for different bundles?

Comment: Right now, Whatever call is coming to `processEvents` method, it will be passed to all the bundles. And `processEvents` method will be called at a rate of 1000/per second.

Comment: One quick question- What I am supposed to log here? `if (!future.isDone()) {
                // log error for this entry
            }` Can you provide an example of that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The reply given by Steinar is correct but this solution is not scalable as you said "in future, it might be possible that I will have more than 5 bundles." and I am sure that you might be adding bundles    at the runtime or afterwards if some tasks are being completed and there might also be a limitation that you can execute atmost 'n' bundles parallely, in that case the executorService.InvokeAll will terminate the pending tasks which have not started if the timer specified is reached.
I have created a simple sample which might be useful to you, This example provides flexibility on how many threads you want to run parallely and you can add tasks or bundles as and when you need.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import testproject.Bundles;
import testproject.ExecuteTimedOperation;

public class ParallelExecutor
{
    public static int NUMBER_OF_PARALLEL_POLL = 4;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {       
         ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NUMBER_OF_PARALLEL_POLL );      
         // Create bundle of objects you want
         List<Bundles> lstBun = new ArrayList<Bundles>();
         for (Bundles bundles : lstBun) 
         {
            final ExecuteTimedOperation ope =new ExecuteTimedOperation(bundles, new HashMap<String, Object>());
            executorService.submit(new Runnable() 
            {
                public void run() 
                {
                    ope.ExecuteTask();
                }
            });
        }   
    }   
}
package testproject;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Random;

public class ExecuteTimedOperation 
{
    Bundles _bun;
    Map<String, Object> _eventData;
    public static long TimeInMilleToWait = 60 * 1000; //Time which each thread should wait to complete task     

    public ExecuteTimedOperation(Bundles bun, Map<String, Object> eventData)
    {
        _bun = bun;
        _eventData = eventData;  
    }


    public void ExecuteTask()
    {
        try 
        {       
            Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() 
            {
                public void run() 
                {   
                    _bun.processEvents(_eventData);                 
                }
            });

            t.start();
            t.join(TimeInMilleToWait);
        } 
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
                //log back saying this bundle got timeout bcoz it was taking lot of time.
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            //All other type of exception will be handled here    
        }
    }
}

package testproject;

import java.util.Map;

public class Bundles 
{

    public void processEvents(final Map<String, Object> eventData) 
    {
        //THE code you want to execute

    }
}
```

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood how the `ExecutorService` works. I have two hardcoded values in the solution I provided; 5 threads in the threadpool and 30 seconds timeout. In a real implementation, both these values should be configurable. Further, even if there are only 5 threads, that doesn't mean that only 5 bundles may be processed, it means that only 5 bundles are processed concurrently. If you had, for instance, 10 bundles. If 1 took 35 seconds to complete, but the other 9 took 1 second to complete, then you would still end up with 9 completed and 1 cancelled processing.

Comment: You're mixing two different paradigms here; using the `ExecutorService` to start threads that does nothing but starting new threads using the old style `new Thread` & `join` approach. Why are you doing that? I don't see what you're gaining by doing that.

Comment: Steinar if you look at the code and question once again, then the comment by you "if you had, for instance, 10 bundles. If 1 took 35 seconds to complete, but the other 9 took 1 second to complete, then you would still end up with 9 completed and 1 cancelled processing." this is what is needed by TechGreeky as his second point in question  "If any bundle is taking some higher time than the timeout settings I have, then I want to timeout those threads and then log back saying this bundle got timeout bcoz it was taking lot of time.". So this comment is not relevant here.

Comment: Steinar I have read the question once again and studied the code. Now I understood the question more clearly as in code the data passed in processEvents(final Map<String, Object> eventData) function do carry the information how many bundles are to be processed, but till now I am not clear with TechGeeky second point "if any bundle is taking some higher time than the timeout settings I have, then I want to timeout those threads and then log back saying this bundle got timeout bcoz it was taking lot of time" but in executor service you have cumulative timeout for all the tasks.

Comment: In that case if there are 20 bundles in event and I can execute only 5 bundles parallely and suppose the first five took 30 seconds or more to complete then the rest 15 bundles will timeout without execution or start of those events.

Comment: You have a valid point about the timeouts; I wondered a bit about that myself. I interpreted it like he wanted a "total timeout for all threads", but I'm not so sure now that I read it again. If the timeout should be per bundle, your solution is closer to what he wants for sure.